# Inference of function return type based on parameters

Tags: typescript

Consider this example:

```
export function foo(foo?: string) {
  return foo ? { foo } : {};
}

const F1 = foo();
const F2 = foo("y");
```

The compiler infers both types of F1 and F2 to be:

```
{
    foo: string;
} | {
    foo?: never;
}
```

Is it somehow possible to convince the compiler to infer `F1` to `{foo:string}` and `F2` to `{}`?

Comment: overloads: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQDMCuA7AxggljDVGGACgEoAuJAbwF9RJZFVMd9CViTOYqBnBHFwYA5pSQ0e-QcJH1w0eMnTY8BIqR4B+aUNFkaoCXDAI0cDsSRaaGpLSRU6AblDzQWAgKQAxAIxIALwa5K4gnhjePgBMQSEARACe8WTOQA

Answer (score 2):

You need to overload your function:

```js
function foo(): {}
function foo<S extends string>(foo: S): { foo: S }
function foo<S extends string>(foo?: S) {
  return foo ? { foo } : {};
}

const F1 = foo();
const F2 = foo("y");
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlxVRN)